# How to Find Average of Column Which Has Zeroes?Average seems to ignore ZERO and NULL while calculating

Tags: sql, average, zero, isnull, nullif

I want to find average as

```
  avg = sum(a*b) / ISNULL( NULLIF (sum(b) , 0) ,1)
```

where a or b can be 0

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample data that exhibits the problem, the output that you expect, the output that you're seeing along with the full code that you're using, and tag the actual RDBMS that you're using. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide sample data and a result you expect?

Comment: Every aggregation function ignores NULL, but not zeros.